# Copy PCL Point Cloud while preserving organization or Ransac + Surface Normal Calculation

Tags: c++, kinect, point-cloud-library, openkinect

I have a point cloud

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>);
```

that I want to copy into

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr finalcloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>);
```

while filtering based on some inliers calculated using ransac.

```
std::vector<int> inliers;
```

I am currently doing this as

```
pcl::copyPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>(*cloud, inliers, *finalcloud);
```

**Problem**:

Since I want to find the normals for this cloud, I need the organization to be maintained. The copyPointCloud function makes the new point cloud height = 1 (see line 188 of [PCL io.hpp](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/common_2include_2pcl_2common_2impl_2io_8hpp_source.html) ).

Has anyone been able to find normals after performing ransac on a pcl?

Comment: I'm not sure, but not all procedures (for normal estimation) need organized point clouds. It may work http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/normal_estimation.php#normal-estimation

Comment: @Kornel This was the tutorial I used and the setInputCloud() function needs an organised point cloud.

Comment: are you sure? [here](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/features_2include_2pcl_2features_2normal__3d_8h_source.html#l00286) isn't any restriction for the ordered/unordered nature. Only the OMP version needs to have organized clouds.

Answer (score 1):

I think this answer is too late and API might changes from 2015.. but I'll answer it.

The normal estimation will work with both organized cloud and unorganized cloud.

### Unorganized Cloud

I'm copying the code from http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/normal_estimation.php
In this code, the KdTree will be used to estimate the neighbours.

```cpp
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/features/normal_3d.h>

{
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

  ... read, pass in or create a point cloud ...

  // Create the normal estimation class, and pass the input dataset to it
  pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> ne;
  ne.setInputCloud (cloud);

  // Create an empty kdtree representation, and pass it to the normal estimation object.
  // Its content will be filled inside the object, based on the given input dataset (as no other search surface is given).
  pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree (new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ> ());
  ne.setSearchMethod (tree);

  // Output datasets
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr cloud_normals (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);

  // Use all neighbors in a sphere of radius 3cm
  ne.setRadiusSearch (0.03);

  // Compute the features
  ne.compute (*cloud_normals);

  // cloud_normals->points.size () should have the same size as the input cloud->points.size ()*
}
```

### Organized Cloud

I am copying the code from http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/normal_estimation_using_integral_images.php#normal-estimation-using-integral-images

```cpp
// load point cloud
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("table_scene_mug_stereo_textured.pcd", *cloud);

// estimate normals
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr normals (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);

pcl::IntegralImageNormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> ne;
ne.setNormalEstimationMethod (ne.AVERAGE_3D_GRADIENT);
ne.setMaxDepthChangeFactor(0.02f);
ne.setNormalSmoothingSize(10.0f);
ne.setInputCloud(cloud);
ne.compute(*normals);
```